# Azure AD CustomEvents causing MsalUiRequiredException

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, .net-5

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp()
   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "a" })
   .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.

If i remove OpenIdConnectOptions events, i dont see any error. Is this a bug ?

```
  services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {

                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Host"))
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://" + context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"] + Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetValue<String>("CallbackPath");
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**`MsalUiRequiredException`**

> Error Code:  AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented
> to use the application with ID '{appId}' named '{appName}'. Send an
> interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

**Mitigation**

Get user consent first. If you aren't using .NET Core (which doesn't have any Web UI), call (once only) `AcquireTokeninteractive`. If you are using .NET core or don't want to do an `AcquireTokenInteractive`, the user can navigate to a URL to give consent: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&scope=user.read`. to call `AcquireTokenInteractive: app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithAccount(account).WithClaims(ex.Claims).ExecuteAsync();`

And also Try with enabling  [Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?view=o365-worldwide) on your  tenant.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-dotnet#common-net-exceptions)